# Call a plugin function inside a page function doesn't works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have created a plugin inside plugins/ called helper.js, but my plugins functions doesn't works when i call him inside another function 
this is my code : **helper.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import $ from 'jquery'
import toastr from 'toastr'

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    test () {
      alert('test is called correctly')
    }
  }
})
```

**pages/index.vue** code :

```
mounted () {
/** Create the cartesian option for products variants **/
const classname = document.getElementsByClassName('main-input')
// call the cartesian function from plugins/helper.js and listen to each .maini-input class on change

const myFunction = function () {
  this.test()
}
for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener('keyup', myFunction)
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you including the mixin in the `index.vue` `mixins` property?  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: no, how can i do that ?

Comment: That api page has a full example

Comment: the same issue :(  .   my plugin function works fine,  but it doesn't work when i call my plugins functions inside myFunction

Comment: Then please update your question to show how you are including the mixin in with your component

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your plugin into the `nuxt.config.js` file?

```
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/helpers.js'
  ]
}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins